# Add series to Excel scatter chart automatically

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I would need to add series to Excel scatter chart automatically as I have hundreds of them. Would it be possible to not do it manually, maybe with VBA?

[chart data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0uGG.png)
And the desired result:
[sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OacGi.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is it possible.. yes. But you have to provide a lot more information. What you have, what you need it to be and what you have tried so far

Comment: I have a couple tutorials that deal with this kind of data: [VBA to Split Data Range into Multiple Chart Series](https://peltiertech.com/vba-to-split-data-range-into-multiple-chart-series/) and [Split Data Range into Multiple Chart Series without VBA](https://peltiertech.com/split-data-range-into-multiple-chart-series-without-vba/)

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track